# MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

New to Mongo and I am taking on online course in web development. I keep getting this on the console when trying run the following.

```
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jlink\OneDrive - Mistras Group, Inc\Personel\Web Develoment Course\Web Development\fruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

```js
//require the Mongoose package (after running >npm i mongoose in Hyper to install it)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
 
//connect to MongoDB by specifying port to access MongoDB server
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB').catch(error => handleError(error)).then(console.log('DB Connected'));

//create a SCHEMA that sets out the fields each document will have and their datatypes
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});
 
//create a MODEL
const Fruit = new mongoose.model ("Fruit", fruitSchema);
 
//create a DOCUMENT
const fruit = new Fruit ({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Great!"
});

//save the document
fruit.save().then(console.log('Should have saved'));
```

I need to solve this problem to move on with the course.

Comment: Is `mongod` running?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same course from Anjela. I had the same issue. I just change the connection URL. May be it will works for you.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");
```

And also sometimes it can may appear strictQuery error after or before the fixing. It it happens then simple add this line before connect the database. It is for the false the strict model in mongoose.

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery',false);
```

I added my complete code snippet here. Happy learning!

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

mongoose.set('strictQuery',false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");


const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty nice"
});

fruit.save().then(() => console.log('yummy'));
```